# How to query the same data with different property

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some User in Firestore like:

```
accountType: 'Owner',
name: 'himel',
email:'himel12@gmail.com'
```

And I have 20 users in DB.

I wanna do a search query based on a users name or email like:

```
userRef.where("name", "==", "himel").get();

or

userRef.where("email", "==", "himel12@gmail.com").get()
```

I am using react and useState for storing the input value

```
const [userQuery,setUserQuery] = useState('');
```

But by doing this i don't know if user writting a name or email to fetch user based on that value.

**Is it possible to make single query for the user using name or email**

Comment: You may be interested by the following article which presents an approach for executing OR queries: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in firebase, if i get what you've asked correctly try this:

```
 import {useState} from 'react'
 const FetchUser = ()=>{
 const [userQuery,setUserQuery] = useState('');
 const [result, setResult] = useState([])
  // you can run this based on a user event for example if the user clicks the button
  userRef.where("name", "==", userQuery).get().then(snapshot=>{
       setResult(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({id: doc?.id, data: doc?.data()})))
  }).then(()=>{
       // if the results length is zero try by email
       if(result?.length===0){
           userRef.where("email", "==", userQuery).get().then(snapshot=>{
               setResult(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({id: doc?.id, data: doc?.data()})))
          })  
      }
  })
  .....
  console.log(result)
  .....
 }
```

**I hope this will give you a clue Good Luck.**

Comment: here is the problem `.where("name", "==", userQuery).get()` in here it can be name or email!

Comment: Try to search using the name, if the results length is 0 then search again using the email. I know there's a better way of doing this, but this is another alternative

Comment: @AsaduzzamanHimel , sorry to bother you with an old post, but I was wondering whether or not this change helped make this answer viable, and if not, what more information do you require? Perhaps we can help? This is mostly so that people that read through this question can be guaranteed and accepted answer. Makes it easier find stuff and all.